# Modify a Google App Engine entity id?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm using Google App Engine NDB. Sometimes I will want to get all users with a phone number in a specified list. Using queries is extremely expensive for this, so I thought I'll just make the id value of the User entity the phone number of the user so I can fetch directly by ids.

The problem is that the phone number field is optional, so initially a User entity is created without a phone number, and thus no value for id. So it would be created `user = User()` as opposed to `user = User(id = phone_number)`.

So when a user at a later point decides to add a phone number to his account, is there anyway to modify that User entity's id value to the new phone number?

Comment: Maybe I do not understand in correct? Get the old entity id, delete it an put the new entity id.

Comment: @voscausa well it's the same entity. The id is the entity's key. In NDB its referred to as id rather than key_name

Comment: NDB Docs: A Key name (i.e., a string key ID) to retrieve or create. So when it is a string, it is a key name.

Comment: @voscausa right, so now is it possible to change this key_name after an entity has already been created?

Comment: Yes I think so. Guido saw no reason for an extra method to get by key_name. Because you can identify if the "NDB id" holds an id or a name (datastore).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entity ID forms part of the primary key for the entity, so there's no way to change it. Changing it is identical to creating a new entity with the new key and deleting the old one - which is one thing you can do, if you want.

A better solution would be to create a `PhoneNumber` kind that provides a reference to the associated `User`, allowing you to do lookups with get operations, but not requiring every user to have exactly one phone number.

Comment: how do you make a reference with NDB?